# D3 js chart inverted issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, html5-canvas

My [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTs9A/2/)

I am studying d3js,i got this implementation of a bar chart with some data.
I need the chart to be inverted.

I tried adding:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(jsonData.year)])
        .range([500, 0]);
```

and calling that on the bars:

```
  .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d);
        });
```

Didnt work..

How do i get around this? I think am missing something..
This is what i want along with the axis:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how's this? http://jsfiddle.net/jTs9A/3/

the problem was your transform, translate coordinates on appending the x and y axes at the bottom.

```
canvas.append("g")
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
canvas.append("g")
    .call(yAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)");
```

you had (0,250) and (-10,-50) before

EDIT:
 http://jsfiddle.net/jTs9A/4/

you needed to add this:

```
 .attr("y", function(d) {
        return  (h- d.year*10);  //Height minus data value
    })
```

where h is the height of your graph area. check the tut in the comments (not enough rep yet)

Comment: Erm,i think you got it wrong,The chart is inverted,the axis is perfect. I will add an image of the output required.

Comment: I have added the required image.